# Como consumir webservice em uma extensão do Chrome?

Tags: web-service, google-chrome

Opa pessoal,

Blz?

Preciso consumir um webservice em uma extensão do Chrome, alguma dica? Já tentei chamar um programa externo usando NAPI, mas vi que está sendo descontinuada no Chrome 43.

Att,

Valdo

Comment: Agradeço pelas resposta, foram muito úteis..... mas alguém teria um exemplo prático? Eu li muita coisa e entendi... mas a dificuldade está em colocar na prática... se alguém puder ajudar... agradeço....

Answer (score 0):

Indico a utilização do [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)

É completo e deve atender suas necessidades.
É bem simples e intuitivo, porém se precisar consultar a documentação, segue o [link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/blog_mentions)

Answer (score 0):

Indico a utilização do [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

O Rest é uma ótima extensão, te ajuda a organizar os seus projetos.

> Ele possui funcionalidades para exportar os seus projetos dentre outras.